# The 'Lying over theorem' for integral ring extension without Zorn's Lemma, when the fields of fraction are a finite extension

Tags: ring-theory, axiom-of-choice, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R\subseteq A$ be an integral extension of integral domains, and $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. The proof that there is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak M$ of $A$ lying over $\mathfrak m$ (that is $\mathfrak m=R\cap\mathfrak M$) consists of two steps:

1. $A\mathfrak m\subsetneq A$.

   $A$ has a maximal ideal containing $\mathfrak m$.

Step 1 is an easy argument using the usual trick with a characteristic polynomial. Step 2 is just an immediate consequence of Zorn's Lemma.

While teaching a class in Galois theory, I was wondering if Step 2 can be done without resorting to Zorn's Lemma if the field extension $\text{Quot}(R)\subseteq\text{Quot}(A)$ of the field of fractions is finite. If it helps, I'm fine if we additionally assume that $R=A\cap\text{Quot}(R)$.

*Question:* Does anyone know a reference or slick proof for Step 2 in this situation without using Zorn's Lemma (or axiom of choice)?

One attempt which I didn't complete is as follows: $A/I$ is an $R/\mathfrak m$-vector space for every ideal $I$ of $A$ containing $\mathfrak m$. So the existence would follow for dimension reasons if $A/\mathfrak mA$ has finite dimension as an $R/\mathfrak m$-space. I haven't checked if that is actually true.

(*Remark:* Here integral domain is a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity and no zero divisors.)

Comment: What is $K$? Also do we know that $A$ even has any maximal ideals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: $K=\text{Quot}(R)$, I fixed the question. I don't know (not assuming Zorn) whether $A$ has any maximal ideals. But even if we knew that there are any, I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: For many applications you can show, without choice, that your rings are Noetherian in the sense of any non empty set of ideals having a maximal element. So appealing to the existence of maximal elements is fairly harmless.

Comment: @Dap: Yes, I know. However I do not want to make any further assumptions on the rings.

Comment: Peter, I don't quite know the answer, but suppose that $\Bbb Q\subseteq A$ and $A$ does not have any maximal ideals. Would that be a counterexample?

Comment: Also, when you say "domain", what *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I clarified the question regarding the term *domain*. Not sure about your other comment; if $A$ is integral over $\mathbb Q$, then $A$ is a field.

Comment: I think you can at least reduce to the case where the dimension of $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ over $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is 1. First, if we can prove this case then we can always replace $R$ with its integral extension $R'=A \cap \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ which itself satisfies $R'=A \cap \mathrm{Frac}(R')$.  Second, if $R= A \cap \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and $A \neq R$ then we can find some $x \in A \backslash R$, and therefore $x \notin \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ so $R'=R[x]$ is such that $[\mathrm{Frac}(R'):\mathrm{Frac}(R)]>1$, but we can easily replace R with R'. Alternating these two steps, we eventually terminate.

Comment: In other words, this problem reduces to the case of the integral closure of a domain (in the domain's field of fractions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer but I think this might provide some insight--see my previous comment. You can at least reduce to the case where the dimension of $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ over $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is 1. First, if we can prove this case then we can always replace $R$ with its integral extension $R'=A \cap \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ which itself satisfies $R'=A \cap \mathrm{Frac}(R')$. Second, if $R=A \cap \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and $A \neq R$ then we can find some $x \in A \backslash R$ and therefore $x \notin \mathrm{Frac}(R)$, so $R'=R[x]$ is such that $[\mathrm{Frac}(R'):\mathrm{Frac}(R)] > 1$, and we can replace $R$ with its integral extension $R'$. Alternating these two steps, we eventually terminate, and we can easily reduce further to the case where $A$ is the integral closure of $R$ (in its field of fractions.)

I am not aware of any constructivity results for this case of the lying-over theorem, but I would keep in mind that according to Banaschewski (edit: Hodges)
[the existence of maximal ideals in every ring is equivalent to the axiom of choice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/98549) while the existence of maximal ideals in Noetherian rings follows from the axiom of dependent choice, so without the axiom of choice it's possible that all Noetherian rings have a maximal ideal and some non-Noetherian rings do not, but (with AC) [the integral closure of a Noetherian domain is not necessarily Noetherian](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404916301864). This isn't a proof of a consistency result that you might want as a negative answer, but if the problem is really about the integral closure, then it seems hard to believe the answer is yes, since integral closures can be highly pathological and even if maximal ideals are easy to construct in the base domain they may be hard to construct in its integral closure.

Comment: Actually Krull implies choice is due to Hodges, not Banachewski. The latter just gave a new proof of the same result.

Comment: @Scott Mutchnik: Thanks for the input. As I expect that more can be said about my question, I'll  leave it open by not accepting your answer. Hope that's alright for you.

Comment: That's alright, it seems that not much has been written about consistency results involving ring theory beyond the most general level.